# Ubuntu 12.10 won't boot after security updates

Tags: 12.10, updates, intel, ubuntu-studio

Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on a Dell studio 1558 laptop (i7 with 4 G of RAM). Everything worked fine... Last week I installed security updates and for some reason it just won't boot after the updates formated my system 3 times and it kept happening. Does anyone know wich are the updates that makes Ubuntu-studio to not boot after install?

Comment: I wonder: "formated my system 3 times" - did you install the system fresh each time?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dual graphics card? See this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1167114

Accordingly to this bug, its happening to all systems that have hybrid graphics, but it has been fixed a few days ago, which means that soon it will be in the updates.
To avoid that bug, simply keep always pressing shift key on boot and select a previous kernel. (Hopefully) it will work.

Edit: please keep in mind that you need to do that each time you boot to avoid that nasty bug until the update land in the repositories.

Regards